# Validate if a form is fully submitted

Tags: javascript, html

I have a school assignment where they ask me to create a pizza form with HTML and Javascript.
They ask for three fields - Size, name and address.

1. If one of the fields is empty, an alert message should pop saying
   what is missing.
2. If the form is valid and full, an alert message should pop saying the full name, address and size.

My problem is that i can't understand how to check if the form is full.

This is the code I wrote so far:

```js
    function validateForm() {
        var errormessage = "";
        if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
        alert (errormessage += 'Please enter your name')
        return false;
        }
        if (document.getElementById('address').value == "") {
            alert (errormessage += 'Please enter your address')
            return false;
        }
    }
    alert("validations passed");
    return true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Page Title</title>
        </head>
        <script src = "script2.js"> </script>
        <body>
            <h3> Pizza Order </h3>
            <form id="pizza-form" onsubmit="return fullForm()" method="post">
                Full name: <br>
                <input type="text" id="name">
                <br>
                Address: <br>
                <input type="text" id="address">
                <br>
                Size: <br>
                <select name="Size">
                <option value="Large">Large</option>
                <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="Small">Small</option>
                </select> <br><br>  
                <input type="submit" value="Order Pizza">
            </form>
           
        </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: *My problem is that I can't understand how to check if the form is full* --> what do you mean by `full`?

Comment: You don't really need to check if the every field is filled out. You check each input field if it's empty. That's fine and works. So if some field is empty, you give an error message. That works too. At the end of your function you give an alert saying that everything is alright and correctly filled out. This point gets only reached if the two checks before didn't stop the function from executing because some input field isn't filled out. So if every field is filled out, the alert at the end tells the user that the form is filled out correctly. No need for an extra check.

Comment: Hi @Guy Sidon, did an answer help you ? If so, can you please mark it as accepted ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the solution. In the HTML code, correct the name of the `onsubmit` function and in your javascript function check all the values together :

```js
function validateForm()
{
  var errorMessage = '';
  var nameValue    = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var addressValue = document.getElementById('address').value;

  if (!nameValue)
    errorMessage += 'Please enter your name \n';
  if (!addressValue)
    errorMessage += 'Please enter your address ';

  if(errorMessage)
  {
    alert(errorMessage);
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    alert('Name : ' + nameValue + '\n' + 'Address : ' + addressValue);
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<h3> Pizza Order </h3>
<form id="pizza-form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  Full name: <br>
  <input type="text" id="name">
  <br>
  Address: <br>
  <input type="text" id="address">
  <br>
  Size: <br>
  <select name="Size">
  <option value="Large">Large</option>
  <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
  <option value="Small">Small</option>
  </select> <br><br>  
  <input type="submit" value="Order Pizza">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

An optimized solution would look like the following :

```js
function validateForm() {
    const errorTable = ['name', 'address']

    const errorMessage = errorTable.map(elem => !!document.getElementById(elem).value ? '' : 'Please enter your ' + elem)

    console.log(errorMessage.join('\n'))
    return errorMessage.every(elem => elem === '')
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Page Title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3> Pizza Order </h3>
            <form id="pizza-form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                Full name: <br>
                <input type="text" id="name">
                <br>
                Address: <br>
                <input type="text" id="address">
                <br>
                Size: <br>
                <select name="size" id="size">
                  <option value="Large">Large</option>
                  <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                  <option value="Small">Small</option>
                </select> <br><br>  
                <input type="submit" value="Order Pizza">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

You just have to type the name of the function you wish to use for validation into the onsubmit attribute of your HTML element.

Your form tag now looks lie this :

```
<form id="pizza-form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

Answer (score 0):

In the manner for which you are attempting to do this, your form submit is calling `fullForm()`

So, change your javascript to:

```
    function fullForm() {
        var errormessage = "";

        if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
        alert (errormessage += 'Please enter your name')
        return false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById('address').value == "") {
            alert (errormessage += 'Please enter your address')
            return false;
        }

    alert("validations passed");



    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add *`else if`* condition with *`else`* condition to submit the valid form

Updated Code:

```
<form id="pizza-form" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

your `validateForm()` function:

```
function validateForm() {
 var errormessage = "";
 if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
  alert(errormessage += 'Please enter your name');
  return false;
 } else if (document.getElementById('address').value == "") {
  alert(errormessage += 'Please enter your address')
  return false;
 } else {
  return true;
 }
}
```

```js
function validateForm() {
 var errormessage = "";
 if (document.getElementById('name').value == "") {
  alert(errormessage += 'Please enter your name');
  return false;
 } else if (document.getElementById('address').value == "") {
  alert(errormessage += 'Please enter your address')
  return false;
 } else {
  return true;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title
    </title>
  </head>
  <script src = "script2.js"> </script>
  <body>
    <h3> Pizza Order 
    </h3>
    <form id="pizza-form" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
      Full name: 
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="name">
      <br>
      Address: 
      <br>
      <input type="text" id="address">
      <br>
      Size: 
      <br>
      <select name="Size">
        <option value="Large">Large
        </option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium
        </option>
        <option value="Small">Small
        </option>
      </select> 
      <br>
      <br>  
      <input type="submit" value="Order Pizza">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```